# Sending Email directly on flex mobile

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flashdevelop

I want to send Email directly from my flex application. Is there any way to send email from mobile. I already tried

`navigateToURL(new URLRequest("mailto:myemail@gmail.com"));`.

It always opens the phones Email application. Is there any way to send email directly from the App.

Thank u.

Comment: You'll have to let a server send the email, just as you would for a regular web app.

Comment: another option would be to build in email client functionality (actually connect to the users email provider) but they would need to provide you with their pop/smtp/user/pass info in a setup process. Here is a library that does that if it is an option for you [Email from Air](http://code.google.com/p/airxmail/)

Comment: Airxmail works fine with system emulator via port-25 and host-smtp.gmail.com. But facing problem while sending from iPhone. I tried with various ports(465,587,25), still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "SMTP Mailer" an ActionScript library for SMTP.
 http://www.bytearray.org/?p=27&cpage=4#comment-584647.